# getting reference error in my first silverlight application

Tags: silverlight

I have getting reference error,

```
The type or namespace name 'ContextMenu' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

but i have already add reference from,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\Client\System.Windows.Controls.dll
```

please help me to solve this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi Look at below link:

[Silverlight ContextMenu was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811221/silverlight-contextmenu-was-not-found/11046789#11046789)

In this link I mentioned other dlls which required for contectmenu. So give refrence of those dll also.

Thanks,
Hitesh

Comment: I already added all this references but the error are same it is.